# C# Enum - Difficulty defining by enumerator

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to learn C# from this tutorial: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/c-sharp-enumerations

It suggests defining "today" as you see below, but when I do I get this error: `'EnumerationTutorial.DaysOfWeek' does not contain a definition for 'today'`

I have tried many different things, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi4wB.png

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace EnumerationTutorial
{
    public enum DaysOfWeek { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DaysOfWeek today = DaysOfWeek.Sunday;
            Console.WriteLine(DaysOfWeek.today);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `today` is an instance of `Sunday` member of your `DaysOfWeek` enum. Your `DaysOfWeek` doesn't have _any_ member called `today`. Feels like you just want to `Console.WriteLine(today)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declares a variable of type DaysOfWeek named today

```
        DaysOfWeek today = DaysOfWeek.Sunday;
```

This accesses the today member of DaysOfWeek, which does not exist

```
        Console.WriteLine(DaysOfWeek.today);
```

Try this instead

```
        Console.WriteLine(today);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Eric, that worked and helped clear it up.